# Showing that a function $f:(X, \mathcal{T}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is right-continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous to a given topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

What I'm asking for is some tips/hints on the following problem. As of writing I have no idea how to even begin proving the claim:

Let $\mathcal{T}' = \{\varnothing, \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{(t, \infty)\mid t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I have to show that a function $f:(X, \mathcal{T})\to \mathbb{R}$ is right-continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous w.r.t. the topology $\mathcal{T}'$ of $\mathbb{R}$, where $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is an arbitrary topological space. The given description of a right-continuity is that $f$ is right-continuous if for every $x \in X, \epsilon > 0$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(x) - \epsilon < f(y), \forall y \in U$. To show that $f$ is cont. w.r.t. the topology $\mathcal{T}'$, we'd have to show that for every $V \in \mathcal{T}'$, $f^{-1}[V]$ is open in $(X, \mathcal{T})$. By right-continuity we know that for every $x \in f^{-1}[V]$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $U \in \mathcal{T}$ s.t. $f(x) - \epsilon < f(y), \forall y \in U$. But how do we extend this fact to imply that $f^{-1}[V]$ is open? Surely we can find a *cover* for $f^{-1}[V]$ by taking the union over all neighborhoods of all elements of $f^{-1}[V]$. But then we only know that $f^{-1}[V]$ is a subset to the union of some elements of $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: That's not the definition of right-continuity. You should look into that.

Comment: @jjagmath My source material is somewhat old and not in English, so translation error is possible. The direct translation of the given definition is downward half-continuous, which I took to refer to right-continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Two thing. First, as hinted in the comments you have the wrong translation. This is [lower semicontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Lower_semicontinuity), not [right-continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Directional_and_semi-continuity).

Second, your proof is on the right track. You are correct to pick, for each $x\in f^{-1}[V]$, an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, and then take the union of these $U$ to  get a cover of $f^{-1}[V]$. The trick is to choose $\varepsilon$ in the definition of lower semicontinuity correctly so that each $U$ is contained in $f^{-1}[V]$ and hence the union is exactly $f^{-1}[V]$.

So here is my hint: Suppose $V=(t,\infty)$ for some $t\in\mathbb R$. Given $x\in f^{-1}[V]$, you know that $f(x)>t$. What can $\varepsilon$ be (depending on $f(x)$ and $t$) so that the $U$ given by the definition is necessarily a subset of $f^{-1}[V]$?